# a library to parse java serialized objects?

Tags: java, serialization

java serializes objects in a well-known and published manner (there's a [spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html)).
what im looking for is a library that can parse a binary blob of serialized objects into something like a graph of [apache beanutils DynaBean](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/DynaBean.html)

such a library would be useful in case i want to "read" (and work with) serialized objects without having the classes themselves in the classpath (or, as in my case, because the classes were refactored and renamed rendering old data unreadable ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong with XML / JSON / BSON ?     Well defined, widely accepted and language agnostic formats.   There is a ton of serialisation libraries with different flavours

Comment: there's nothing wrong with any of the above. in fact, theyre much better than java serialization for most things. im asking the question because i have to work with java serialization this time

Comment: Java.io.objectoutputstream does what you need. Mostly. But it is brittle - one slight change in object signatures, and your data is binary waste. And sending it to another box is PITA. if you need binary format, try BSON

Comment: here's the precise problem: the product im working on has been using serialization to save stuff to files for years (bad, i know). some classes were moved in a recent refactoring, which made older files unreadable (no class found exceptions all over the place) - panic ensued and I need to "make it work". right now I've subclassed ObjectInputStream to solve the immediate crisis, but it occurred to me that such a library might be generally useful in these situations

Comment: So you already have a problem I was preaching against :)  Unfortunately I'm not aware of ready library doing this,   but it would be possible to write wrapper  parsing stream directly. Protocol is not that wickedm and it was already done (http://www.andlabs.org/presentations/Attacking_JAVA_Serialized_Communication-slides.pdf contains usefull links)    You may start with  Skljarows defence ( decompile OIS it with jad and modify to suit your  needs)

Comment: since such a library probably doesnt exist, and i definitely agree that using serialization for persistance is a terrible idea, i'll just accept this answer